# Structure declaration difference between visual studio 2010 C and Ubuntu C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to follow Zed Shaw's "Learn C the Hard Way" online course. I have encountered a problem when trying to compile ex17 using the c compiler in Visual Studio 2010. I always get an error from around line 100 of the code.  However, when I try to compile the exact same file while using an Ubuntu virtual machine, the code compiles just fine.  The error is generated in the following code at the "{.id"  where the compiler generates an error at the ".".  Can someone explain why this error occurs in one compiler and not another?  Since it occurs in a windows environment how can it be avoided in the future?

```
void Database_create(struct Connection *conn)
{
int i = 0;

for( i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
    // Make Prototype to initialize
    struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0}; //Syntax error generated here
    // then assign it
    conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
        }
 }
```

Note:  This occurs in visual studio command prompt regardless if the C compiler switch is activated or not.

Answer (score 1):

`struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};` is a C99 construct - specifically the `{.id = i, .set = 0}` initializer is a 'designated initializer'.

MS VC++ doesn't support C99 constructs in general. In some cases you can work around this by compiling as C++, since several common C99 features (such as declarations permitted after statements in a block) are supported in C++.  However, designated initializers aren't part of C++ either.

You'll either need to use a compiler that supports C99 on Windows (such as MinGW's GCC), or modify the code to be compatible with C90.  If there's not too much C99-specific stuff, that's probably not too hard:

```
struct Address addr = {0};
addr.id = i;
```